# How to build a diagram in in R and apply data to the diagram?

Tags: r

I have structure that looks roughly like this...

```
            _ _ 
           |   |  
          o|   |o
    ___oo_o|   |o_oo___
   |                   |
   |_______     _______|
       oo o|   |o oo
          o|   |o
           |   |
           -----
```

It is just a simple plus frame platform with 2 IR beams going across the entrance of each platform (Infrared beams marked by the circles). There are double the amount of circles because one is the light and the other is the receiver. An object is placed in the center of the platform and every beam break is recorded in seconds when it moves around. If the beam is continuously broken, it gives the time breaking the beam (i.e. there may be repeated seconds in the arrays for the beams).

Edit: The numbers listed as "0:", "5:", "10:" can be disregarded. They are just line markers. Also, the other numbers in the array correspond to the amount of time passed from the previous beam break.

Here is some example data of the arrays from the output text file...

```
D:
     0:        0.000        0.000        0.000        8.000       51.000
     5:       51.000       86.000       91.000       96.000       99.000
    10:      100.000      110.000      115.000      116.000      117.000

E:
     0:        0.000        0.000        0.000        0.000        0.000
     5:        0.000        4.000       35.000       35.000       36.000
    10:       36.000       36.000       39.000       39.000       39.000 

F:
     0:        0.000        0.000        0.000        0.000       34.000
     5:       57.000       63.000       64.000       74.000       79.000
    10:       79.000       79.000       87.000       89.000      137.000

G:
     0:        1.000        1.000        3.000        3.000        0.000
     5:        0.000        0.000        1.000        1.000        1.000
    10:        1.000        1.000        1.000        1.000        1.000  

H:
     0:        0.000        9.000       86.000       91.000       96.000
     5:      105.000      110.000      115.000      116.000      117.000
    10:      130.000      130.000      131.000      131.000      132.000

I:
     0:        0.000        0.000        0.000        0.000        0.000
     5:       36.000       38.000       54.000       54.000       54.000
    10:       54.000       54.000       55.000       55.000       73.000

K:
     0:        0.000        1.000       35.000       66.000       67.000
     5:       67.000       68.000       69.000       70.000       70.000
    10:       70.000       70.000       87.000      137.000      142.000

L:
     0:        1.000        2.000        4.000        4.000        4.000
     5:        5.000        5.000       11.000       12.000       13.000
    10:       14.000       16.000       17.000       17.000       19.000
```

The array output corresponds to the picture below to give you an idea for beam placements and data...

```
            _ _ 
           |   |  
          K|   |K
    ___IE_F|   |F_GL___
   |                   |
   |_______     _______|
       IE D|   |D GL
          H|   |H
           |   |
           -----
```

Here is an example dataframe of the arrays...

[image: example]

I want to determine the following:

- How long it took for the object to make first entrance to each of the 4 arms (latency)
- Time spent in each arm
- Idle time sitting in the beams of each arm
- Number of half entrances for each arm (only first beam break)
- Number of full entrances for each arm (both beams broken)
- Number of half exits for each arm (only first beam break)
- Number of full exits for each arm (both beams broken)
- Time spent in the center section (i.e. it exited the arm but did not touch any other
  beams

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example and *restrict yourself to a single question*. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I added an example dataframe after pulling data from the text file.

Comment: @jc2525 you have added a screenshot of a dataframe, not an actual reproducible example. You will find that people are not willing to type down numbers from screenshots. Have a look at how to structure a minimal reproducible example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to increase the likelihood of receiving an answer.

Comment: Especially, please use `dpu()`